FlutterError: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.)

catch (e) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(
            'Error: ${e.toString()}'),
      ),
    );
  }

I made registration page and the firebase is working fine and users are also registered.
But this exception is popping up again and again.
please tell me how to fix

1. Solution by checking if the widget is part of the widget tree:
If the widget gets removed from the widget tree (for example, when navigating to a different screen), calling ScaffoldMessenger.of(context) will cause an error because the context is no longer valid. The mounted property ensures that this doesn’t happen.
catch (e) {
  // Ensure the widget is still mounted before showing the SnackBar
  if (mounted) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('Error: ${e.toString()}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}


2. Solution Using GlobalKey:

No need for context: Since we are using the GlobalKey, you don’t
need to pass the context around.

No need to check mounted: This approach doesn't require checking mounted, as the ScaffoldMessenger will manage its state.


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Define a GlobalKey for the ScaffoldMessenger
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> scaffoldMessengerKey =
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Assign the key to the ScaffoldMessenger
      scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('SnackBar Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              /// Show the SnackBar using the ScaffoldMessenger key
              scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('This is a SnackBar!'),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: const Text('Show SnackBar'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

